# Is using the one passphrase for many keys safe?

Tags: ssh

As I'm using many keys and for my self confidence I don't want to use to many passphrases to it (at some point it might be non comfortable, as I keep passwords in KeePass) I wondered if the same passphrase for many keys is safe.

Of course I want to leave aside the case whenever someone take over my passphrase and have then access to the all keys.

My consideration is, if someone with for example 100 private keys with the same passphrase can evaluate it, or at least limit its possible number? Is there some salt mechanism included into generating the hash of passphrase, or the passphrase is checked against the actual factories stored in the key, and as those factories are different from key to key, always the "factories derived hash" will be different?

Comment: It looks like a salt is used. also see discussion here (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/security-of-passphrase-protected-private-key)